# cordova phonegap android 5 time picker missing Set button Cancel and Clear buttons only

Tags: cordova, android-5.0-lollipop

cordova 3-6-3, android 5 lollipop

tap on time input pops up the time picker with the Set button missing.

got email from user with screenshot showing that in my app (jquerymobile 4.0 UI), with android 5 (lollipop on nexus device) the time picker comes up with Cancel and Clear buttons only. The SET button is missing, so there is no way to change the time, while with 4.2.2 there is no issue.

To test further I did the following tests:

1)
I made a clean webpage (not an app, just a web html page) with the time input field and ask the user to try it. He is prompted with the correct popup with Cancel, Clear, Set buttons.
So, Android 5 lollipop is OK on a clean html page loaded in the browser.

2)
Created a helloworld basic cordova app (no JQM just plain cordova app) with the time input in the main page and sent it to the user. He installed and reported the same issue, he sent a screenshot showing the same problem: Set button missing with Cancel and Clean button only.

Any ideas for a workaround or how to fix this?

One solution could be to use regular text input and limit the input to 0123456789: chars only, but dunno if this is a good option.

Comment: To replicate create a HTML file with <input type="time"> and open it in Android 5.0. The Timepicker will appear on touch offering only "Cancel" and "Clear" options

Comment: I think its a bug from lollipop as its working fine on 2.3 and 4.X

Comment: Have you got anywhere with this as Ive got the same issue?

Comment: @saibotd created the html with time input and android 5 works, created also a basic cordova app without JQM and Android has the same issue, so at lest we know JQM is not the issue.

Comment: @nath no news yet, found just bug issues around, but no solutions yet.

Comment: There are plugins for date and/or time picker, you could try one (eg look for DatePicker in https://build.phonegap.com/plugins ).

Comment: Good news, it's fixed! As you can see here (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=434695) but it's not available for the users yet. They don't know when will be shipped.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by using Crosswalk instead on the default webview that Cordova uses by default. When you install Crosswalk this is going to replace the buggy webview that Android comes with and uses Crosswalk browser instead.

If you are considering using Ionic Framework in the future just make sure that you have a version later than ionic 1.3.2. You should be able to add crosswalk by running this command

```
$ ionic browser add crosswalk
```

Comment: Ionic version 1.3.2 does not exist, the available version at the moment of writing is 1.0-rc1: which library were you referring to?